# Run task at specified times

Tags: java, android

I'm fetching a JSON string from a server and write it to a file. I'm using `java.util.Timer` to run the task repeatedly every hour.

I want to run it exactly 00:00, 01:00, 02:00... 24:00(yes hourly).

Do I have to use `Calendar` + `AlarmManager`?

This is the code:

```java
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class LoggerServices extends Service {
    LoggerTask loggerTask;
    TimerTask timerTask;
    Timer timer;
    Handler handler;

    public LoggerServices() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "CHANNELID")
                .setContentTitle("Example Service")
                .setContentText("Population Logger")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_mode_edit)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();

        startForeground(1, notification);
        handler = new Handler();
        timer = new Timer();
        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        loggerTask = new LoggerTask();
                        loggerTask.execute();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 3600000);
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "SERVICE DESTROYED");
        if (loggerTask != null) {
            loggerTask.cancel(true);
            timerTask.cancel();
            timer.cancel();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: `TimerTask` keeps the app alive at all time which is bad and probably not even possible due to Androids aggressive battery management. Simply schedule an hourly task without any timers

Answer (score 0):

The best option for you would probably be `AlarmManager`. You don't need to use any `Calendar` class or anything similar, because `AlarmManager` is already built for use with time in mind, because it needs to happen at an exact time.

One option is to use an alarm type. By doing this you are using the official time intervals provided by `AlarmManager`. You could also make your alarm go off every two hours by doing a loop of alarm managers, although that won't be that memory efficient and your android app could crash. Also, avoid using `Services` when trying to do exact-time works.

Because of the unlimited possibilities, it is impossible to create an implementation, so it would be better for you to decide for yourself.

Take a look at the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager

Also, look at repeated alarms here if you want to do something related with alarms: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms